For all $x \geq k \geq 1$: $\left(1+\frac{1}{x+k}\right)^k \leq 1+\frac{k}{x+1}$

For all $x \geq k \geq 1$:
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{x+k}\right)^k \leq 1+\frac{k}{x+1}.
$$

I wanted to prove this by maximizing the $\log$ of the ratio:
$$
f(x)=k\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x+k}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{x+1}\right).
$$
It is easy to see that the limit for $x\rightarrow\infty$ is $0$. Now I have to show that $f(1)\leq 0$ for all $k$ and that the function has no zeros.
I get
$$
f(1)=k\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{1+k}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right).
$$
but I dont know how to show that this is less than $0$.

Can someone help me here? Am I on the right track? Or is there a simpler shorter way of proving the inequality?

Motivation: This is a step in a proof for the Theorem of Sylvester and Schur:
$$
\binom{n+1+k}{k}=\left(1+\frac{k}{n+1}\right)\binom{n+k}{k} > \left(1+\frac{1}{n+k}\right)^k(n+k)^{\pi(k)}>(n+1+k)^{\pi(k)}.
$$
There is no proof of the above inequality and I wanted to prove it. Thanks for any hints!

As for proving the inequality, I would first look to Bernoulli's inequality, or the Binomial expansion...

Ah, have you tried to take the derivative for $f$? When $x>k$, we have $f'(x)<0$ so just check $x\to\infty$: which $f$ has value of zero.

FYI, regarding the step in the Theorem of Sylvester and Schur, if you're referring to the last part, i.e., $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+k}\right)^k(n+k)^{\pi(k)}>(n+1+k)^{\pi(k)}$, please see my answer to Not clear on the last step of Andrew Granville's proof of the Sylvester-Schur Theorem.

@JohnOmielan Thank you! I am actually referring to the exercise in that proof, the inequality.

By Bernoulli inequality $(1 + u)^r \le 1 + ur$ for all $u \ge 0$ and $0 \le r \le 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \left(1 + \frac{k}{x+1}\right)^{1/k}
 &= \frac{1 + \frac{k}{x+1}}{\left(1 + \frac{k}{x+1}\right)^{1 - 1/k}}\\[6pt]
 &\ge \frac{1 + \frac{k}{x+1}}{1 + \frac{k}{x+1}(1 - 1/k)}\\
 &= 1 + \frac{1}{x+k}.
\end{align*}
We are done.

You seem to have swapped $k$ and $1$ around, and the exponent is $k$ not $1/k$. Perhaps you could explain how to finish it.

@Lucenaposition It is $\left(1+\frac{1}{x+k}\right)^k \leq 1+\frac{k}{x+1} \iff 1+\frac{1}{x+k} \leq \left(1+\frac{k}{x+1}\right)^{1/k}.$

The inequality can be proved in a completely elementary way:

Note first that if $1+t\geq 0$, then by induction one has
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
(1+t)^n \geq 1+nt
$$
Indeed it is an equality if $n=1$ and if the inequality holds for $n$ then since $(1+t)\geq 0$ we see that
$$
(1+t)^{n+1} \geq (1+nt)(1+t) = 1+(n+1)t+nt^2 \geq 1+(n+1)t
$$
where the final inequality follows because $t^2 \geq 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$ and $n \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$.

Now for the inequality
$$
(1+\frac{1}{x+k})^k \leq 1 + \frac{k}{x+1}
$$
if we first put the terms on each side over a common denominator and then use the fact that $x \mapsto 1/x$ is decreasing on $\mathbb R_{>0}$ (where both sides are positive for $x\geq -1$) we see that the inequality is equivalent to each of the following:
$$
\begin{split} 
&(\frac{x+k+1}{x+k})^k \leq \frac{x+k+1}{x+1}\\
&\iff  \frac{x+1}{x+k+1}  \leq (\frac{x+k}{x+k+1})^k\\
&\iff 1-\frac{k}{x+k+1}\leq (1-\frac{1}{x+k+1})^k \\ 
\end{split}
$$
but the final formulation follows from ($\dagger$) above with $n=k$ and $t=-1/x+k+1$, noting that $1-1/(x+k+1) = \frac{x+k}{x+k+1} >0$ for $k \in \mathbb Z_{>0}$ and $x \in \mathbb R$ with $x \geq 1$.


Addendum
As the comments point out, the inequality in 1. is known as Bernoulli's inequality and it holds for real exponents $r$ with $r \geq 1$ and all $t$ with $t\geq -1$.
If one uses $(1+t)^r = \exp(r\log(1+t))$ then the inequality is equivalent to $r\log(1+x) \geq \log(1+tr)$. This follows immediately from the fact that $\log$ is concave, that is,
$$
s\log(x)+(1-s)\log(y) \geq \log(sx+(1-s)y), \quad \forall s\in [0,1].
$$
In turn the fact that $\log$ is concave is equivalent (since $\log(t)$ is smooth) to the fact that $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\log(t))<0$, where $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\log(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}(1/t) = -1/t^2<0$ for all $t >0$.
Now for any $r\geq 0$ if we take $x=1$, $y=1+rt$ and $s = 1-1/r\leq 1$ then
$$
\frac{r-1}{r}\log(1)+\frac{1}{r}\log(1+rt)\leq \log(\frac{r-1}{r}.1 + \frac{1}{r}(1+rt)) = \log(1+t)
$$
that is, $\log(1+rt)\leq r\log(1+t)$ or $1+rt\leq (1+t)^r$ as required. Note that this argument requires $1+rt$ to be non-negative, that is, $t>-1/r\geq -1$. However, if $-1/r\geq t\geq -1$ and $1+t\geq 0 \geq 1+tr$, then $(1+t)^r\geq 0 \geq 1+tr$ follows trivially, and hence $(1+t)^r \geq 1+tr$ holds for all $r \geq 1$ and $t\geq -1$.
Finally, note that if $0<r<1$ then the opposite inequality holds, that is $(1+t)^r \leq 1+tr$ as can be checked using the same technique as above, or alternatively, by noting that $a^r$ is the inverse of $a^{1/r}$, so that $(1+t)^{1/r} \geq 1+t/r$ which is equivalent to $(1+t)\geq (1+t/r)^r$. Setting $t_1=t/r$ this becomes $(1+rt_1)\geq (1+t_1)^r$ as required. Note that $t_1\geq -1$ if and only if $t \geq -r>-1$, so that the inequality holds for all $t_1\geq -1$.

FYI, Wikipedia's "Bernoulli's identity" article, in its Real exponent section, states that $(1+x)^r\ge 1+rx$ for every real $r\ge 1$ and $x\ge -1$, i.e., $1+x\ge 0$.

FYI, once again, rather than using $x \mapsto 1/x$ is decreasing on $\mathbb R_{>0}$ to show $(\frac{x+k+1}{x+k})^k \leq\frac{x+k+1}{x+1}\iff\frac{x+1}{x+k+1}\leq(\frac{x+k}{x+k+1})^k$, we have for all real $a,b,c,d\gt 0$ that $\frac{a}{b}\le\frac{c}{d}\iff\frac{a}{b}\left(\frac{bd}{ac}\right)\leq\frac{c}{d}\left(\frac{bd}{ac}\right)\iff\frac{d}{c}\leq\frac{b}{a}\iff\frac{b}{a}\geq\frac{d}{c}$, i.e., switch around the numerators and denominators on both sides & reverse the inequality. Also, it's not "Bernoulli's identity", as I stated above, but "Bernoulli's inequality", as in the answer.
